# Importing a module from a different path in the same project

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following project structure :

```
-project
  -src
    -package1
      -script1.py
      -__init__.py
    -package2
      -script2.py
      - __init__.py
    -__init__.py
```

Now `script1.py` includes two functions :

```
def my funct1():
    print("Hello")

def my funct2():
    // do something
```

Now I want to run `funct1()` in `script2.py`. I am new to something like that as I always write my whole code in `main.py` and that's it.
I have searched for this problem and I wrote the following code in `script2.py` :

```
from src.package1.script1 import *

    funct1()
```

This gives me the following error :

```
    from src.package1.script1 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Somebody please help me to import the function. I have another question, when I solve the import error, do I directly call `funct1()` in `script2.py` or do I need to do something extra, like including a main function in `script2.py` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use relative imports like:

`from ..package1.script1 import *` since `src` has it's own `__init__.py` it's all the same module.

This will work if calling `script2` as a module, i.e.

```py
python3 -m project.src.package2.script2
```

rather than

```py
python3 project/src/package2/script2.py
```

In the later case you'll get the error  `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

If this wasn't the case, i.e. `package_1` and `package2` are separate modules, you should just add the module path to sys.path by including:

```py
import os
import sys

current file = __file__
src_directory_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(current file))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(src_directory_path, "package1"))
```

in `package2/__init__.py`. Then your call things like
`import package1`

For more on relative imports see the answers to [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: what are ".." before the "package1.script1 import * ?

Comment: I have tried  from ..package1.script1 import * but I got this error ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: The ".." are referring to moving "two steps upwards" in the package hierarchy. If you had another script `script2a.py` next to `script2.py`, you would use `from .script2a import ...` - the single dot referring to moving one step up.

Comment: This relative import will only work if you're calling script2 as a module (using the -m flag). I'll put this in the answer.